# heroku db:pull Failed to connect to database NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When I run `heroku db:pull` I get a `NoMethodError`. Fervent googling has failed to provide a solution.

```
rails_app[master*]/
↪ heroku db:pull --remote [app] --confirm [app]
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Auto-detected local database: postgres://127.0.0.1/[db name]?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://127.0.0.1/[db name]?encoding=utf8' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Failed to connect to database:
  NoMethodError -> undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass
```

The result is the same when I supply the database name as `postgres://localhost/app_development`

I have taps, pg, sequel installed:

```
rails_app[master*]/
↪ gem list --local | grep -E taps\|pg\|sequel
pg (0.15.1, 0.15.0, 0.14.1)
sequel (3.46.0, 3.20.0)
taps (0.3.24)
```

And just in case, my rails config/database.yml

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: app_development
  encoding: utf8
  min_messages: warning
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test
```

I'm on Rails 3.2.13.

Has anyone run into this and come up with a solution?

Comment: It came up fine with `rails db` as well as with `psql app_development`: psql (9.2.2) app_development=# \quit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db:push` and `db:pull` are currently deprecated; please use pgbackups to import and export data

- [Heroku DevCenter: Importing and Exporting Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

Comment: This is true, however, I suspect it's probably a good idea if the Heroku CLI version is upgraded, too: it shouldn't crash like that.  I think.